# Are real numbers uncountable in the any interval?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

It is known that,

> $$\operatorname{card}_{\mathbb{R}}
> (0,1)=2^{\aleph_0}$$

I could not find the answer to this question:

So, for **any** interval can we say?

> $$\operatorname{card}_{\mathbb{R}}
> (\alpha,\beta)=2^{\aleph_0}$$

For example,

Are real numbers uncountable in the interval

$$\left(\sqrt2,\sqrt2+\left(10^{{{10}^{10}}^{10}}\right)^{-1}\right) ?$$

If so, is there a proof?

Comment: The interval must have a non-empty interior.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe So, Is the answer yes?

Comment: @Elementary It's not difficult to find a bijection between any two (open, non-empty) intervals, proving they have the same cardinality. You should try it. Then you're not only guessing, you will have proven it!

Comment: @Arthur what is open and non empty interval?  And why open interval? can you explain me this with short comment? Thank you.

Comment: An open, non-empty interval is any interval $(a,b)$ which actually contains numbers (non-empty), but doesn't contain its endpoints (open). You can include intervals which do contain one or both endpoints into this if you'd like, but at this stage that will only clutter things, so I would personally recommend looking into that _afterwards_.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you so much again.

Comment: What does "$\text{card}_{\Bbb R}$" mean???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! The map $$x \mapsto (\text{tower of 10})^{-1}x+\sqrt{2}$$ from $(0,1)$ to $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}+(\text{tower of 10})^{-1})$ is a bijection. Here $(0,1)$ is uncountable, so your open interval is uncountable too!